# Change signed-in user in Windows 8 simulator?

Tags: windows-store-apps

Visual Studio lets you fire up a Windows 8 simulator to test apps. By default, the simulator uses the same user account as my machine. Is there a way to specify a different account?

Comment: I'd like to know this too. I don't think so, based on my attempt to switch to a different account in the simulator. It disassociated my Microsoft account from the host machine as well.

Answer (score 0):

This answer comes with one important caveat: It will require an installable (registerable) version of Windows 8.

Use the Hyper-V Manager to create a new virtual machine and install Windows 8 on that. You will be able to create whatever accounts you need, either local or Microsoft accounts. Install the Visual Studio 2012 Remote Debugging tool on that machine. In my case, I joined the VM to my local WORKGROUP.

In your VS 2012 project, you can then select Remote Machine instead of Simulator or Local. If, for some reason, the remote connections dialog box doesn't show up to allow you to select the VM, you can also go to Properties > Debug > Start Options and select Remote Machine and use the Find button to locate it.

Comment: This gets you part of the way there, and is the closest answer I've found so far, but this doesn't allow you to use the simulator tools (screen rotation, fake geolocation, touch mode, etc.)